# Take any type that can yield a char iterator, plus &str

Tags: rust

I want to write a function `tokenize` that takes `char`s from an iterator. Like this:

```
fn tokenize<F: IntoIterator<Item=char>>(file: F)
```

If I want to use a `&str` with this function, I can do it like this:

```
tokenize("foo".chars())
```

That works OK.

Now, I'd like to avoid that `.chars()` specifically for type `&str`, since I know that, if I'm given a `&str`, I can make it what I want by calling `.chars()`.

I tried declaring a new trait, `IntoChars`, and implement it for `&str`:

```
trait IntoChars {
    type T: Iterator<Item=char>;
    fn into_chars(&self) -> Self::T;
}

impl<'a> IntoChars for &'a str {
    type T = Chars<'a>;
    fn into_chars(&self) -> Self::T {
        self.chars()
    }
}
```

If then I make my function like this:

```
tokenize<F: IntoChars>(file: F)
```

it works. Nice! But I want to implement `IntoChars` also for *any* type that can give me chars, ie. is `IntoIterator<Item=char>`.

```
impl<T: IntoIterator<Item=char>> IntoChars for T {
    type T = T::IntoIter;
    fn into_chars(self) -> Self::T {
        self.into_iter()
    }
}
```

That doesn't work. For two reasons:

1. `IntoIter::into_iter` takes a `self`, but `IntoChars::into_chars` takes a `&self`. This is specifically because I don't want to consume `&str` when calling its `into_chars` method unnecessarily. Is there any way to achieve both?
2. OK, let's say that I make `IntoChars::into_chars` take a `self`. This still doesn't work; I get: `` error: conflicting implementations for trait `IntoChars` [E0119] ``. But if I remove the `impl<'a> IntoChars for &'a str`, I get `` error: the trait `core::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for the type `&str` ``. Why is is conflicting then?

Any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Re 1: `&str` is `Copy`, calling a method with `self` receiver will just copy the reference and not consume anything. (If you see `&self` methods in standard library string methods, that's because those traits are implemented for `str`, not `&str`)

Comment: Please note that you should only [ask one question per question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at your two implementations, which I've rewritten in the more verbose form:

```
impl<T> IntoChars for T
    where T: IntoIterator<Item = char>

impl<'a> IntoChars for &'a str
```

What should the compiler do when whoever owns either the trait `IntoIterator` or the type `&str` decides to implement `IntoIterator` for `&str`? All of the sudden, you'd have *conflicting implementations* for the same trait; There are two ways that `IntoChars` would be implemented for `&str`.

Other keywords for this problem are *trait coherence* and *orphan rules*.

To be able to compile this, you'd need [*impl specialization*](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1210), which is an RFC that has not been accepted yet.

Comment: I think you mean "whoever owns either the trait `IntoIterator` or the type `&str` decides to implement `IntoIterator` for `&str`?".  In this example, there is already an implementation of `IntoChars` for `&str`.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, although _currently_ there is no conflict, Rust prevents this just in case in the future the "owner" of `&str` decides to implement `IntoIterator<Item = char>` and provoke the conflict. Makes sense. Thanks!